# Google Bearer token: which one is the correct one?

Tags: lua, google-cloud-storage

I'm completely new with Google Cloud Storage and I'm trying to build a HTTP request via GET method. I'd like to access a page in my cloud storage, but I need an authorization key, like: httpRequest:write("Authorization: Bearer ~~token here~~"). But I don't know what token I should use exactly. I'm doing this in Lua, if it is relevant and the unique problem is the authentication, because when I try to access a public object I don't have any problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be honest I don't think this is specifically a Lua question, as it can be applied pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud uses OAuth 2 for authentication. Your requests will begin with some sort of credentials (a private key, a Google account password, a refresh token) and end with an "access token", which will go in that spot in your Authorization header. There are a variety of different approaches based on which sort of entity you are authenticating as. For instance, a standalone application usually has a private key associated with a service account, and it uses that key to sign a request for an access token. If you are writing an app that runs with some user's Google credentials, there's a complex three-party OAuth handshake that ends with you receiving an access token.

Let's assume you're writing a standalone app and it will use a service account. When you create your service account, you'll get a private key. You'll construct a "JWT claim set" describing the scope of the access that you'd like. Here's an example:

```
{
  "iss":"761326798069-r5mljlln1rd4lrbhg75efgigp36m78j5@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.readonly",
  "aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
  "exp":1328554385,
  "iat":1328550785
}
```

Then you'll sign it with your private key and submit it to Google's OAuth2 service, and the response will contain an access token. Here's an example response:

```
{
  "access_token" : "1/8xbJqaOZXSUZbHLl5EOtu1pxz3fmmetKx9W8CV4t79M",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600
}
```

Now when you make requests for the next hour, you'll include an `Authorization: Bearer 1/8xbJqaOZXSUZbHLl5EOtu1pxz3fmmetKx9W8CV4t79M` header.

This whole thing is rather complicated, which is why there are helper libraries in most languages (although not Lua, that I know of). Also, if your program is running in GCE, you could take advantage of Application Default Credentials, which would help simplify matters.

This whole process is documented here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2. The flow I described was the one for "Service Accounts." Another option would be to get a refresh token

Comment: I should use my Lua library to do it and it should be inside my new API, which I'll create soon. I was wondering if I could build a pure HTTP request string and get a response from that with the access token. Here is an example:

httpRequest:write("GET /myPage.html HTTP/1.0\r\n")
httpRequest:write("host: myBucket.storage.googleapis.com\r\n")
local response = httpClient:get(httpRequest)

This is a simple page request, but I wonder if I could do a similar thing for the access token and the response variable would have it.

Comment: Yes, you can. The Google OAuth 2 process is a RESTful HTTP process. You could certainly invoke it directly.

Comment: I feel I'm on the right way now. I'm gonna do some more research though. Thank you for your help!